# AttributeError: 'submitButton' object has no attribute '_row' - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-buttons

I keep getting this error for a Discord.py button and after searching the internet I still cant find out why it is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

AttributeError: 'submitButton' object has no attribute '_row'

```py
    class submitButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self):

        @discord.ui.button(label="Submit Entry", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, row=3)
        async def submitEntry(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: 
                              discord.Interaction):

            await self.view.submit_response(interaction)
```

```py
    async def submit_response(self, interaction:discord.Interaction):
        
        # Created messageEmbed here #
        
        await interaction.user.send(embed=messageEmbed)
        await interaction.response.send_message(content="Your answers have been 
                                                submitted!", view=self, ephemeral=True, 
                                                delete_after=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because you put your button when defining `__init__`. You usually define `__init__` as follows:

```
class submitButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Also your indentation is wrong (although that might just be how you pasted it in the question). OUTSIDE of `__init__` should you add your buttons.

```
class submitButton(discord.ui.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @discord.ui.button(label="Submit Entry", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, row=3)
        async def submitEntry(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            await self.view.submit_response(interaction)
```